# Parameter with special charcter is converting while sending get request

Tags: php

I am facing one issue. I am sending data through `REST API` and accepting the parameter value using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
if($action==11){
   $query=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
   $result=between('searchKey=', '&', $query);
   echo $result;
}
function after ($this, $inthat)
    {
        if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $this)))
        return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat,$this)+strlen($this));
    };
function before ($this, $inthat)
    {
        return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this));
    };
function between ($this, $that, $inthat)
    {
        return before ($that, after($this, $inthat));
    };
```

Here I am sending the data like below.

```
http://example.com/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php?action=11&searchKey=12%
```

Here my problem is I am getting output as `12%25` of `echo $result` where I need to get only `12%` .while `%` coming its adding some extra thing. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You know you could just use `echo $_GET['searchKey'];` instead? This will do the url decoding for you

Comment: _“its adding some extra thing”_ - that’s called URL Encoding ...

Comment: ok,but I am using some different function. any option to do this using this way ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Try This https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/percent-sign/

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP decodes incoming URL parameters automagically into the [`$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

If that isn't an option (let's say the URL is stored somewhere) you can parse the query string yourself with the poorly named [`parse_str()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

Finally, to extract the query string from a URL you can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Here you are a full example with all the pieces:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php?action=11&searchKey=12%25';
$query_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query_string, $get);
var_dump($query_string, $get);
```

> ```
> string(25) "action=11&searchKey=12%25"
> array(2) {
>   ["action"]=>
>   string(2) "11"
>   ["searchKey"]=>
>   string(3) "12%"
> }
> ```

It's worth nothing that [standards](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) assign certain meaning to certain characters and `%` has been chosen as escape character:

> A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a
>      component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the
>      allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the
>      component.  A percent-encoded octet is encoded as a character
>      triplet, consisting of the percent character "%" followed by the two
>      hexadecimal digits representing that octet's numeric value.

That means that a single literal `%` needs to be encoded as `%25` (which still represents just `%`). If you don't follow the rules you're on your own: you can't use standard libraries and functions and you're likely to confuse third-parties—for instance, any browser where you type the URL will gladfully encode it for you, potentially ruining it.